# npm throws error "Cannot find module 'readable-stream'"

Tags: node.js, npm

Just installed node.js in windows 8. When I enter node -v in command prompt it successfully gives the version number v4.1.2 but when I use any npm command I get following error

```
module.js:338
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous>           
(C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you add your package.json file ?

Comment: What is `are-we-there-yet` and why is it running? What command are you running to get the output you've shown? You have not given enough info.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am new to this. I just dont know whats going on. I wanted to install gulp. I read it needs nodejs installed. So I installed lates version from their website. I followed their first 2 instructions and on the second one.. when I ran the command of npm I got this error. and now I am getting error on anything that starts with npm. Just dont know how this works.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error (Windows 10). Here's how I solved it:

1. Uninstall nodejs through the control panel.
2. Go to C:/Users/*$username*/AppData/Roaming      (note that the AppData folder is hidden by default).
3. Scroll down to the npm and npm-cache folders and delete both of them.
4. Reinstall nodejs.

Give that a try, I hope it works out!

Comment: I had node 5.1.0 installed and updated to 5.6.0 and got the exact same error that @Vivek Padhye had - this fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `readable-stream` module ?

Try `npm install readable-stream`

Comment: instead of showing images you can add you package.json file

Comment: @Toanalien I am sorry but I could not understand you. I just installed nodejs and followed their instructions on their website but cant get npm working. I dont know about package.json. tried searching it in istalled directory and there are many package.json files.

Comment: @VivekPadhye If `npm install` is throwing an error, then there should be a `npm-debug.log` generated in your current directory. Could you upload that file as, say, a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) so I can take a look at what error you are seeing? The image you posted is apparently deleted now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
npm install readable-stream
```

Comment: above line gives me same error, nothing gets installed

Comment: Are you behind an enterprise firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
I didnt solve this err not to uninstall nodejs.
But installed latest one.
https://nodejs.org/en/